# Problem in PowerApps accessing to SQL Server table with computed column built with a function

Tags: sql-server, azure, calculated-columns, powerapps, bad-gateway

introducing my context :

- I make PowerApps solutions for small businesses
- I use Azure SQL server as DB
- I rescently discovered the computed column in SQL Server which should help me to simplify the way my PowerApps applications works

Here is my issue :
When I do a direct computed column formula, as : firstName + lastName, everything is fine with PowerApps, persisted or not persisted, I can patch on the table

When I implement a function throught the computed column formula, as : ([dbo].fnCalcPrixMoHtElmtFacturable) I cannot Patch anymore on the table, the following message shows "bad gateway"

It's quite strange for me, I don't really understand what is the link with a gateway, but I tried multiple times and it really is this computed column function thing that unable the Patch from PowerApps.

It is very frustrating for me as I was planning a lot of those computed column and it end up being quite restrictive for me right now.

Has anyone an idea from where to start to solve this problem ?

Thx

Sylvain

detail of the function, which works fine in SQL Server:

```
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fnCalcPrixMoHtElmtFacturable]    
Script Date: 24/03/2021 11:28:10 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCalcPrixMoHtElmtFacturable] 
(
    @constIdTableElmtFacturable AS INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @constIdProjet AS INT
DECLARE @constIdPiece AS INT
DECLARE @constIdZone AS INT
DECLARE @constIdProduit AS INT
DECLARE @constIdOperation AS INT
DECLARE @varType AS VARCHAR(15)

DECLARE @varNbCouche AS INT
DECLARE @varThMo AS INT
DECLARE @varSurface AS INT
DECLARE @varResult AS INT

SET @constIdProjet = (SELECT idProjet FROM tableElmtFacturable WHERE ID=@constIdTableElmtFacturable)
SET @constIdPiece = (SELECT idPiece FROM tableElmtFacturable WHERE ID=@constIdTableElmtFacturable)
SET @constIdZone = (SELECT idZone FROM tableElmtFacturable WHERE ID=@constIdTableElmtFacturable)
SET @constIdProduit = (SELECT idProduit FROM tableElmtFacturable WHERE ID=@constIdTableElmtFacturable)
SET @constIdOperation = (SELECT idOperation FROM tableElmtFacturable WHERE ID=@constIdTableElmtFacturable)
SET @varType = (SELECT [type] FROM tableElmtFacturable WHERE ID=@constIdTableElmtFacturable)

SET @varNbCouche = (SELECT nbCouche FROM tableElmtFacturable WHERE ID=@constIdTableElmtFacturable)
SET @varSurface = (SELECT surface FROM tableZone WHERE ID=@constIdZone)

IF @varType = 'produit'
BEGIN
SET @varThMo = (SELECT thApplique FROM tablePivotProduitDansProjet WHERE idProjet=@constIdProjet AND idProduit=@constIdProduit)
END

IF @varType = 'opération'
BEGIN
SET @varThMo = (SELECT thApplique FROM tablePivotOperationDansProjet WHERE idProjet=@constIdProjet AND idOperation=@constIdOperation)
END

SET @varResult=@varThMo*@varNbCouche*@varSurface

RETURN @varResult
```

END

Comment: No real point in posting your TSQL UDF scalar function. It is the query and how the resultset is used in powerapps that is the issue.

Comment: Side note: I'm sure it works fine in SSMS, but it could be written in a single query of about 3 lines, and if it was an inline TVF it would be much faster also